# Строку в значение

Tags: php, строки

Доброго времени суток! Мне нужно написать цикл, который будет брать с каждой строки текст до запятой, и вставлять её в alt, а в src номер строки, то есть:

```
<img src="$str_num" alt="$str_text">
```

кто нибудь сможет подкинуть такую функцию? просто не оч знаю работу со строками и foreach (

Comment: а пример строки, которую нужно обработать можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$file = file('file.txt');
foreach($file as $str_num => $line){
  $str_pos = strpos($line, ',');
  $str_text = substr($line, 0, $str_pos);
  print '<img src="$str_num" alt="$str_text">';
}
```

Comment: @bazaev05, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Покажите пример текста

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'раз,два, три , четыре пять';

$str = preg_split('/\s?,\s?/', $str);

foreach($str as $src => $alt)
{
    echo '<img src="'.$src.'" alt="'.$alt.'" />';
}
```